# как реализовать вью "написать разработчику" в приложении? swift

Tags: swift, uiview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать вью "написать разработчику" в приложении swift?
Чтобы при открытии этого экрана сразу было все как в email, но с уже заполненным полем "кому". Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func sendEmail() {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients(["you@yoursite.com"])
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)
        presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // show failure alert
    }
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто откройте почтовый клиент из программы и пусть пишут:

```
let email = "your@email.com"
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(email)")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

P.S. Пробовать на реальном устройстве.

Answer (score 0):

Можете не реализовывать целый контроллер, а просто добавить кнопку "Написать разработчику" и по нажатию на нее открывать нативный клиент для мыла.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: ViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["nurdin@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Нагло скопипащено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963514/sending-email-with-swift).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но был найден еще более простой способ, более мне подходящий